# How to add another child to my firebase collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

So i am trying to find a user with the UserID of with the same value as the variable `UserID`and once found I want to add a new child to my collection. I am unsure how to do this, I have tried using

```
var UserID = 123;

var userEvent  = firebase.database().ref('/users').orderByChild("id").equalTo(UserID).child('Events');

 var eventsData = {
    testdata: 99
 };

 
 userEvent.push(eventsData);
```

I have tried the above however I am getting the following error message.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_22__.default.database(...).ref(...).orderByChild(...).equalTo(...).child is not a function
```

Is there a specific way I could do this?

Below is how many users collection looks like currently

[image]

Comment: Could you add an example of the Events child?

Comment: so Events is the child that i want to add. Currently my users collection is has no child @Hoobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pointing out that something is wrong with the ref. I think the issue is that `EqualTo()` returns an array or object, but I'm not 100% sure.

I would reorganize the code to this:

```
var userEvent  = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + UserId).child('Events');
```

You should be able to push to that ref.

Comment: thanks i will try this. But how do does it know to look at the id field in my database? This is why i used EqualTo() and orderbychild

Comment: @Jim The `6o1C...` acts as an object key. Firebase DB stores everything as basically one big JSON object. Each value inside the forward slashes acts as keys, and Firebase will go down whatever branches the URL inside the ref points to.

So you don't really need the `id` field, but then you need to worry doing `Object.keys()` if you need it... and that can be a pain. I wouldn't worry about it too much. (at least while you're getting the hang of things)

Comment: GREAT Work. Worked like a charm

Comment: Glad I could help! I've had a lot of fun with Firebase, but it's pretty different to other DB's and the way it handles errors can be pretty unhelpful and frustrating. I had to `console.log()` a ton to get use to it.